# How do i access names of one model from relationship of three models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many

I need to print out in the index view, all **items** from a certain **city** under  **category** with id 2(any number).So far i have instance of all items in the city(as shown below),now i want to filter them by category.How do i do that?This is my code below

```
    class CategoryController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @city= City.find(session[:city_id])
    @items=@city.items
    end
    end
```

index view

```
     <%=@item.each do |item|%>
     <%=item.item_name%>
     <%end%>
```

Models

```
       class City < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :items 
       end

       class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :city
   belongs_to :category
       end

       class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :items
       end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:
You should be able to do something like:

```rb
@items = Item.find_by_city_and_category("city", "category")
```

Or something like:

```rb
@items = Item.where(:category => "category", :city => "city")
```

View:

```rb
@items.each do |item|
 item.name
```

Comment: But how do i enter the category id and city though.I need to hardcode category_id and access city_id dynamically from the session as shown above.

Comment: You can do it with this URL `/category/:id/city/:city_id/items` so you can set the category_id and city_id. You can use session as well if you prefer. Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html